# Rmarkdown printing data.frame inside function

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I simplified my problem by using iris data.frame. The problem is that I cannot print a data.frame inside a function in Rmd File.

This is my "test.Rmd" file:

````
```{r results='asis',echo=FALSE}  
fun_test<-function(dfiris){
  out<-tryCatch(
    { 
      cat("  \n### Inside fun_test. Printing dfiris -> FAIL  \n")
      cat("  \n")
      kable(dfiris) # It does not work
    },
    error=function(cond){return(NA) }    
  )
}
```

```{r results='asis',echo=FALSE}  
library(knitr)
df1<-head(iris)
cat("  \n## Start. Outisde fun_test. Printing df1 -> OK  \n")
cat("  \n")
kable(df1)
fun_test(df1)
```
````

So, I render it to Word document:

```
render("test.Rmd","word_document")
```

And the output is that:

[image]

Why the data.frame "dfiris" is not printed? Is there something wrong in my "fun_test" function?

Comment: Thanks, I was missing kable for printing the data.frame and nothing was printed in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't return the result, just assigned it to `out`.

Try:

```
fun_test<-function(dfiris){
  tryCatch(
    { 
      cat("  \n### Inside fun_test. Printing dfiris -> FAIL  \n")
      cat("  \n")
      kable(dfiris) # It does not work
    },
    error=function(cond){return(NA) }    
  )
}
```